# whirr unable to connect to custom AMI - EC2

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, apache-whirr

Hi I am trying to do a Hadoop deployment on EC2 using whirr. If I use one of the publicly available Ubuntu AMI, my cluster gets deployed and everything runs fine. However, if I use my own custom RHEL AMI, then my launch fails because of ssh. Here is what I know is going on. Whirr creates a new key pair and uses that to log into the instance. However ssh into the instance fails. That tells me that something is wrong with the settings of my new instance. I would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu AMI's have "ubuntu" as the default user - RHEL AMIs have "root" as the default root user. Double-check what username whirr uses while setting up a new node - I suspect its using the "ubuntu" default username and hence is not able to SSH into the RHEL node.